# Add counter to comments

Tags: 7, comments

I would like to add a coutner to comments, so when I view a node I've something like:

> ```
> Comment #1 - Text 
> Comment #2 - Text 
> Comment #3 - Text
>
> and so on..
> ```

Is there a way to obtain this?
Obviously #1, #2 and #3 are number relative to every singole node.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not such a simple question as might at first appear. Comments can be threaded so they appear as multiple nested lists. They can also run over multiple pages if there's more than the limit (50 by default). So can you clarify how you would like the numbering to work in those cases?

Comment: I've not nested comments, because this comments are like sign on petitions, so $id is enough

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Override `comment.tpl.php` and add the following to it:

```
<?php print 'Comment #' . $id; ?>
```

(You obviously add it to the spot in the template where you want the comment number to appear.)

Here is the contents of my override for `comment.tpl.php` for Bartik;

```
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?> clearfix"<?php print $attributes; ?>>

  <div class="attribution">

    <?php print $picture; ?>

    <div class="submitted">
      <p class="commenter-name">
        <?php print $author; ?>
        <?php print 'comment #' . $id; ?>
      </p>
      <p class="comment-time">
        <?php print $created; ?>
      </p>
      <p class="comment-permalink">
        <?php print $permalink; ?>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="comment-text">
    <div class="comment-arrow"></div>

    <?php if ($new): ?>
      <span class="new"><?php print $new; ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
    <h3<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $title; ?></h3>
    <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>

    <div class="content"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
      <?php
        // We hide the comments and links now so that we can render them later.
        hide($content['links']);
        print render($content);
      ?>
      <?php if ($signature): ?>
      <div class="user-signature clearfix">
        <?php print $signature; ?>
      </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div> <!-- /.content -->

    <?php print render($content['links']); ?>
  </div> <!-- /.comment-text -->
</div>
```